# HQL Query using join to fetch data from tables

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need help regarding to write `HQL` query to fetch data from three table using join.

```
public class PostMessages  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long messageid;
     private String message;
      private Set videosDescriptions = new HashSet(0);
     private Set postImageses = new HashSet(0);
}

public class PostImages  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long imageId;
     private String smallPicPath;
     private String largePicPath;
     private PostMessages postMessages;
 }

public class VideosDescription  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long videoId;
     private String videoPath;
     private String videoTitle;
     private PostMessages postMessages;
    }
```

In **PostMessages.hbm.xml** I mapped both classes as follow

```
<set name="postImageses" table="post_images" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
     <key>
     <column name="messageid" />
     </key>
  <one-to-many class="hibernetMappings.PostImages" />
</set>
<set name="videosDescriptions" table="videos_description" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
  <key>
   <column name="message_id" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="hibernetMappings.VideosDescription" />
 </set>
```

Above are my pojo classes I want to fetch all `postMessages` and `postImages` and `videoDescription` details for given message id how to fetch it.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins

Comment: your usage of plural form is a bit weird... It seems more natural to call it PostMessage instead of PostMessages because it represent 1 message.

Comment: @AdrianShum got your point. It was generated with Netbeans.

Comment: Never trust such kind of generated code that is mean to be read by human.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following query which is working properly

```
select distinct pm
     from PostMessages as pm
     left join fetch pm.postImageses as pi
     left join fetch pm.videosDescriptions as vd 
     where pm.messageid=67
```

If is there any other way for getting this query please provide it

Comment: This is possibly not a good idea to fetch like this, because the query will give you cartesian product of that two one-to-many relationship.  If you are having 100 postImages and 100 videoDescriptions for a PostMessages, the SQL is going to give you 10,000 records which is not optimal.  I'd rather suggest you to query it by 2 queries, each of them contains only 1 relationships, so that there is only 200 records in total got transmitted.

Comment: @AdrianShum pboth tables are based on foreign key relationship with `PostMessages`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change the fact that the result SQL is going to give you cartesian product.

Comment: @AdrianShum so what should be query to fetch relevant data based on join

Comment: @AdrianShum how to check a query is suitable and optimized query

Comment: you may simply turn on sql log of hibernate to inspect the SQL.  In most case, HQL->SQL translation is quite straight-forward.  For example, a join/join fetch is going to be translated to a SQL join.

Comment: @AdrianShum So insted of using hql I should use native sql while fetching data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49529/discussion-between-xrcwrn-and-adrian-shum)

Comment: sorry chat is blocked in office, but in brief, no, that's not what I mean.  change to use native sql is not going to help because the problem is about cartesian product.  Normally we would want to issue 2 queries, one for each "path" of ~ToMany relationship.  I may add an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

The answer from OP may work, but blindly joining two "path" of ~ToMany relationship is going to make the resulting SQL an inefficient query which give cartesian product for the result.

To simplify the story, assume we have entities like this:

```
public class Message {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Image> images;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Description> descriptions;
}
```

if you are retrieving Message + its images + its descriptions by

```
from Message 
left join fetch images 
left join fetch descriptions 
where id = :id
```

if that message contains 100 images and 100 descriptions, the resulting SQL is going to give you 10,000 records.

A more proper way to fetch this is by issuing two queries.

```
from Message left join fetch images where id = :id

from Message left join fetch descriptions where id = :id
```

With first-level cache of Hibernate (or any JPA implementation), you can get the result of either one of the queries and you will have both images or descriptions fetched.

Just to avoid confusion, if you have structure like this:

```
[Foo]  1-->* [Bar]  1-->* [Qux]
```

It is fine to do

```
from Foo foo join fetch foo.bars bar join fetch bar.quxs qux where foo.id = :id
```